# How to catch invalid image from third party website when using PHP imagecreatefromstring

Tags: php

I understand that we could use the below way to catch invalid image but for my case it is not able to catch the download timeout.
I am trying to get a image from a third party website and my script is keep loading
and no response at all.Maybe the way that I use to catch error is not good enough?
Could anyone advise a better way to catch invalid file and download timeout? Thanks!

```
$url = "https://www.example.com/image.jpeg";
if (checkRemoteFile($url))
{
    $imagefile = $url;
    $resource = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imagefile));

    if ($resource == true)
    {
      echo "Image Good";  
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Image Bad"; 
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid file";
}

function checkRemoteFile($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // don't download content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if(curl_exec($ch)!==FALSE)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided script works fine for me, to debug it check the curl error:

```
function checkRemoteFile($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // don't download content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === false) {
        error_log(curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result !== false;
}
```

This will log an error any time you get a bad response or timeout. If you're getting timeouts it could be that the host is down, I tested it with https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg and it worked fine.